# Installing ibm_db2 on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, db2

I have been trying to get an IBM DB2 driver up and running so that I connect to a DB2 instance from PHP for quite a while to no avail. My system is running Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP 7.3.

Here are the steps I have tried.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878

- Ensure `ksh` is installed on the Linux machine:

```sh
sudo apt-get install ksh
```

- Downloaded the Data Server Driver Package (dsdriver) from IBM's website. I downloaded IBM Data Server Client Packages Version 10.5 Fix Pack 10 (Linux x86) as this matches the current DB2 version that I am targeting. You need an IBM account if you don't already have one before you can download the driver.
- Once on the download page, I note the URL of the file, then run the following commands on the Linux machine:

```sh
mkdir -p /opt/ibm

cd /opt/ibm

wget https://path/to/file/v10.5fp10_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz

export IBM_DB_HOME=/opt/ibm

tar -zxf v10.5fp10_linuxx64_dsdriver.tar.gz

cd dsdriver

./installDSDriver

pecl install ibm_db2

DB2 Installation Directory? : /opt/ibm/dsdriver
```

I cannot proceed with the installation due to a `Makefile` error:

```sh
Makefile:194: recipe for target 'ibm_db2.lo' failed
make: *** [ibm_db2.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: Why is this tagged as php?

Comment: @AaronJonk I removed the tag. I am eventually going to be leveraging the driver using PHP code but I suppose that is not relevant to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some tinkering, t looks like PHP 7.3 isn't supported. There is an open PR (at the time of this writing) that implements some changes to address this.

https://github.com/php/pecl-database-ibm_db2/pull/6

Changing the PHP version to 7.2 solved the installation problem:

https://tecadmin.net/switch-between-multiple-php-version-on-ubuntu/